# How to use R to generate output like a pivot table

Tags: r, pivot

I am trying to automate a report that i usually do in Excel using Pivot tables where i drop school into rows and Date Registered into Columns and Values. I also want a row with School and columns with Date registered by month in 2020 only.

My dataset has three columns e.g.
School, Date Registered, Student_ID
St John 01/02/2020       D10460A
Marist  01/04/2020       D20546A
St John 01/02/2020       D15468A
St John 01/02/2019       D52194A
Marist  01/04/2016       D54798A

I would appreciate your help with this.

Comment: The dplyr package and this tutorial should point you in the right direction - https://rstudio-conf-2020.github.io/r-for-excel/pivot-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

This approach can address you to the right path for further exploration:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(Date.Registered=as.Date(Date.Registered,'%d/%m/%Y'),
         Year2020=ifelse(format(Date.Registered,'%Y')==2020,1,0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Student_ID,values_from=c(Date.Registered,Year2020))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 11
  School Date.Registered~ Date.Registered~ Date.Registered~ Date.Registered~
  <chr>  <date>           <date>           <date>           <date>          
1 St Jo~ 2020-02-01       NA               2020-02-01       2019-02-01      
2 Marist NA               2020-04-01       NA               NA              
# ... with 6 more variables: Date.Registered_D54798A <date>,
#   Year2020_D10460A <dbl>, Year2020_D20546A <dbl>, Year2020_D15468A <dbl>,
#   Year2020_D52194A <dbl>, Year2020_D54798A <dbl>
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(School = c("St John", "Marist", "St John", "St John", 
"Marist"), Date.Registered = c("1/2/2020", "1/4/2020", "1/2/2020", 
"1/2/2019", "1/4/2016"), Student_ID = c("D10460A", "D20546A", 
"D15468A", "D52194A", "D54798A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```